# JavaScript / Google Script - Transpose "Row" Array into "Column" Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, transpose

Good afternoon,

I am attempting transpose a "row" array (or 1D array) into a "column" array (or array that is one array containing individual arrays within it) to allow me to set values to a single column (downward multiple rows) instead if it being one row across multiple columns

I attempted using a push loop and a map function but neither attempt succeeded:

```
function myFunction2() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Source1");

  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn()

  var endRange = lastColumn-3

  //Retrieve values into array named "items"
  var items = ss.getRange(16,4,1,endRange).getValues()
```

Transpose attempt # 1:

```
  var colArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
    {
      colArray.push([items[i]]);
    }
}
```

Output for Attempt # 1:

```
[[[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]]]
```

Transpose attempt # 2:

```
  var colArray = items.map(function (el){
      return [el];
  });
```

Output for attempt # 2:

```
[[[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]]]
```

The intended output I would like to have is:

```
[[item1], [item2], [item3], [item4], [item5]]
```

Would there be a way to achieve the intended output?

Comment: Transpose attempt #2 works and outputs as your intended output: https://jsfiddle.net/z5kj17wa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script of `var items = ss.getRange(16,4,1,endRange).getValues()`, `items` is 2 dimensional array like `[[value1, value2, value3,,,]]`. So, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
  var colArray = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
    {
      colArray.push([items[i]]);
    }
}
```

#### To:

```
var colArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
  colArray.push([items[0][i]]);
}
```

And,

#### From:

```
var colArray = items.map(function (el){
    return [el];
});
```

#### To:

```
var colArray = items[0].map(function (el){
  return [el];
});
```

#### Note:

- Or, when you want to transpose the values including the several rows and columns, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    const colArray = items[0].map((_, i) => items.map(row => row[i]));
  ```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)